# how can I make UI running in a separate process appear to be in my process?

Tags: cocoa

The Apple Help Viewer is an example of what I want: its a separate process but doesn't have a menu bar, doesn't appear in the dock, and floats on top. So it appears to be running in the current process. How can I achieve this with Cocoa?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A little googling with the right keywords and I arrive at the solution:

Add the following to the Info.plist file:

```
<key>LSUIElement</key>
<string>1</string>
```

This is courtesy of http://uselessthingies.wordpress.com/2008/05/18/an-app-without-dock-icon-and-menu-bar/